# Same browser displaying differently on different computers

Tags: html, css

I am facing the very strange problem in HTML/CSS.I am using chrome 12.0.742.122.
Now the same html page I am using with css styles applied on that on two different machines having Windows XP and Windows 7 Enterprise OS.
What I am observing is certains elements are giving different effects in the browser.
i.e different font-weight, font-size etc.
Can you please suggest the solution for this ???
(Note - I have googled for this issue and found something like there are different OS on different machines so that chrome is behaving differently.)
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Comment: Have you used a CSS Reset? More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset

Comment: You can't exactly expect all HTML to view the same across browsers, unless if you use full image and imagemap for your pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that one computer has ClearType fonts enabled and the other does not.

See the ClearType tuner on this Microsoft page for an example http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartype/tuner/step1.aspx

Having ClearType turned on causes the font to look bolder and larger in most cases, see the bellow image of your question, both samples were taken from the same version of Firefox on the Same Windows XP machine, one with ClearType turned off (top image), one with it turned on (bottom image).

[image]

Comment: Very good example given by you                                   Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Antialiasing or not (e.g. ClearType settings, what Re0sless showed), other possible reasons might be:

- different screen resolutions (or dpi settings)
- different browser window size (if some sizes are dependent on this size)
- different default font (or font size) settings (if you don't override them all in your stylesheet)

Normally this is no reason to worry - your page should be usable even with small differences in the look.